# which libs are a header file belongs to

Tags: linux, drm

```
OS:Debian9 Linux4.4 
Hardware：ARMv9
```

How do i know which libs is a header file in `/usr/include/` belongs to?

for example, 
there is an error when I build `camera-app-gstreamer`:

```
camera-app-gstreamer/xcore'
drm_display.h:30:17: fatal error: drm.h: No such file or directory
 #include <drm.h>**
```

I fixed it by `apt install libdrm-dev`, after installing `libdrm-dev`, header files named `drm.h`, `drm*.h` appears in `/usr/include`.

now, I have Make problem , it shows:

```
conftest.c:29:41: fatal error: linux/atomisp.h: No such file or directory
#include <linux/atomisp.h>
```

and how can I find which lib it belongs to ?

Thank you.

Comment: as you're using ARM and the filename is atomisp.h, I would try searching the hardware vendors site. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the package content search of your distribution, in this case you can find it [here](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_contents).

If you cannot find the filename through that search, it means there is no debian package providing it.

Comment: It is very helpful , thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 2):

In case you know the complete path to the file and in case it is installed (maybe on a computer where it works), you can go with this dpkg cheat sheet to find out which package installs it:

- `dpkg-query -W <pattern>` — list locally known packages matching given pattern
- `dpkg-query -l` — list all locally known packages
- `dpkg -i <packagefile>` — install the package in the given file
- `dpkg -r <package>` — remove the given package
- **`dpkg -S /path/to/file`** — show the package which installed the given file

If you want to find out whether a file is installed on a system, you can use the `locate` tools.

If you want to find out which package will install it, you should install the `apt-file` tools and use them:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update  # will take a while but needs not to be repeated often
apt-file search drm.h
```

This will list the packages your package management system knows which contain a file with this as part of the name.  You can append `| grep '/drm.h$'` to find only the ones which have exactly this file.